# Install Zeppelin on Mac with brew : Java 1.7 is required

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to install Apache Zeppelin on macOS High Sierra. Following the doc (https://www.datageekinme.com/setup/setting-up-my-mac-zeppelin/) :

```
hlepouse@Hadriens-MacBook-Pro:~$ brew install apache-zeppelin
apache-zeppelin: Java 1.7 is required to install this formula.
Install AdoptOpenJDK 8 with Homebrew Cask:
  brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

However I already installed AdoptOpenJDK 8 :

```
hlepouse@Hadriens-MacBook-Pro:~$ brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
No changes to formulae.

Warning: Cask 'adoptopenjdk8' is already installed.
```

```
hlepouse@Hadriens-MacBook-Pro:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

```
hlepouse@Hadriens-MacBook-Pro:~$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    14, x86_64: "OpenJDK 14"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_242, x86_64:  "AdoptOpenJDK 8"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_171, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
```

```
hlepouse@Hadriens-MacBook-Pro:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong here.
And why is Java 1.7 required, when I'm advised to install AdoptOpenJDK 8 ? I couldn't find a way to install Java 1.7 either.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Java 7 is already EOL, we removed it in [this PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/50688).

I just upload one in my tap, let me know if that works for you.

```
brew install chenrui333/tap/apache-zeppelin
```